# Constructing objects for external libraries using a model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if it's more appropriate to use a separate class (such as a factory?) to construct an object. While the code works, I am concerned about bloating of the model and the tight coupling.

To construct the said object I need:

1. environment variables like api tokens
2. some of the user's attributes from the model
3. classes from the library

Here's the relevant snippet within my `user model` that creates an AdWordsSession object for use in the third-party library:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
...
   public function adWordsSession($customer_id = null){
        if(!$this->google_auth_token) {
            return null;
        }

        if( $this->adWordsSesssion &&
            (
                (isset($customer_id) && $this->adWordsSesssion->getClientCustomerId() == $customer_id) ||
                (!isset($customer_id) && $this->adWordsSesssion->getClientCustomerId() == $this->adwords_customer_id)
            )
        ){
            return $this->adWordsSesssion;
        }

        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder)
            ->withClientId(env('ADWORDS_CLIENT_ID'))
            ->withClientSecret(env('ADWORDS_CLIENT_SECRET'))
            ->withRefreshToken($this->google_auth_token)
            ->build();

        $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
            ->withDeveloperToken(env('ADWORDS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN'))
            ->withUserAgent(env('ADWORDS_USER_AGENT'))
            ->withClientCustomerId($customer_id ?: $this->adwords_customer_id)
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            ->build();

        $this->adWordsSesssion = $session;

        return $session;
    }
...
}
```

I am also interested to know if it applies to the reverse, using a class returned from the library (web service) to construct a model object. Should this be a static method of the model or a separate factory class. Code follows:

```
class AdWordsCampaign {
    public static function fromAdWordsClass(Campaign $campaign, AdWordsCampaign $adWordsCampaign = null): AdWordsCampaign {

        $self = $adWordsCampaign;

        if(is_null($adWordsCampaign)) {
            $self = new self;
            $self->criterions = $self->defaultCriterions();
            $self->extensions = $self->defaultExtensions();
        }

        if($campaign->getId()) {
            $self->fieldsHelper()->id = $campaign->getId();
            $self->setPublished();
        }

        $self->fieldsHelper()->name = $campaign->getName();
        $self->fieldsHelper()->status = $campaign->getStatus();
        $self->fieldsHelper()->advertisingChannelType = $campaign->getAdvertisingChannelType();
        $self->fieldsHelper()->advertisingChannelSubType = $campaign->getAdvertisingChannelSubType();

        $self->fieldsHelper()->budget = arrayify_object(
            $campaign->getBudget() ?
                $campaign->getBudget() :
                CampaignFields::defaultBudget()
        );

        return $self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this as a service in Laravel, and use IOC to resolve my dependencies.

I would make a service, called `AdWordsCampaign`. This would resolve its dependencies in constructor, namely `OAuth2TokenBuilder` and `AdWordsSessionBuilder`, although these two classes are good candidates for services themselves (a factory pattern is most of times is a sign you should abstract creation of class into a service provider).

Then I would implement a method in this service, `adWordsSession` which takes two parameters: a `User` instance and `$customer_id`. Then it has everything it needs to to its job.

I would also implement the reverse case using a service. Semantics are the same.

As for static method, I would avoid them. If you like them, use a Facade. They enable you to use a service anywhere you want.

I strongly suggest to read Laravel docs about services and providers and IOC and Facades. It will give you enough insight about how they work, and where to use them.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you see yourself using `new *` in your codes, it seems your could use a service/provider and inject it.